# How to simplify to get a compact set of inequalities from a given set of inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Given a number $m\in \mathbb{N}$, I need to choose $\alpha,\beta,k$ such that they satisfy a given set of inequalities. How can I simplify the set of inequalities into a compact set of inequalities. Is there any general procedure? How many inequalities would I need at the end?

Set of inequalities to be satisfied.

$\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

1. $\alpha > 0$
2. $\beta > 0$
3. $k > \frac{m}{2}$
4. $1+2\alpha-\beta > 0$
5. $2-(\alpha+\beta) > 0$
6. $1-\alpha(2k-1)>0$
7. $1+\beta > 0$
8. $1-\alpha > 0$
9. $\beta - \alpha(2k-1) > 0$
10. $2\beta>0$

I know there are some silly redundancies but there are some non trivial ones, so I need a generic procedure and what to expect at the end.

Answer (score 1):

From $(1), (2), (3), (7), (10)$
$$\{ \alpha, \beta , k-\frac{m}{2} \} \gt 0$$
From $(4) , (8)$
$$\alpha \lt 1$$
$$\beta \lt 1+2\alpha $$
From $(5) $
$$\beta \lt 2-\alpha $$
Both implying that $\beta \gt \alpha$

From $(6), (9)$
$$ k \lt \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
$$k \lt \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{ \beta}{\alpha}$$
I can summarize, by reducing it to
$$0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$$
$$0 \lt \beta \lt 1+2\alpha$$
$$\{  \beta -\alpha , k-\frac{m}{2} \} \gt 0$$
$$\beta -\alpha(2k-1) \gt 0$$

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer.